# Clarification of off-topic regarding specifications

Tags: discussion, support, scope

From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> if your question generally covers… (...) a software algorithm, or software tools commonly used by programmers (...) then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

But it also says:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book (...) or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow (...).

Given the importance that specifications have in the technical world in general and in software especially, I would consider it strange if questions regarding specifications should be considered off-topic. However, specifications are frequently published in book form and are almost always an "off-site resource".

Nevertheless, there is the tag [`specifications`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/specifications/info), which gives several examples. One of which is the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), available from the Oracle web site (off-site means "site other than Stack Overflow" I assume), and available as a [printed book](https://lccn.loc.gov/2014936248), too.

I consider this is contradictory and needs some clarification.

Comment: Questions **about** specifications, are OK. Questions asking where to find them, are not.

Comment: @Oded: Consider the example I gave. Would it be OK to ask: "Is "\uu2126" a legal Java String and where is that specified?".

Comment: Yes, that's fine. You are not asking for a book recommendation or where to find the whole specification, just a very narrow part of it.

Comment: And if I don't even know that that this is specified in the Java Language Specification and if I even don't know if there is a specification at all, the question would still be OK?

Comment: Yes. It is a narrow question, that doesn't take a whole book to answer and can have a definite, correct answer.

Comment: My motivation for this question is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31022320/4428150

Comment: That's a very broad question. It certainly reads like a request for off-site resources.

Comment: The phrasing isn't working well for you there. Instead of asking if there is documentation or reference, if it were to simply ask "what are they properties....", I expect it wouldn't get closed.

Comment: Very broad??? The answer would be essentially a list of a few Strings.

Comment: Sure, but the phrasing seems to suggest a book or other large reference material that is off-site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144461/discussion-between-gustave-and-oded).